# python re.split gives me unexpected character

Tags: python

```
sent = r'下列函数中,值域是(0,+\\infty )的共有( )‎'
res = re.split(r'(\([^()]*?[\u4e00-\u9fa5]+[^()]*?\))', sent)
print(res)

['下列函数中,值域是(0,+\\\\infty )的共有( )\u200e']
```

Why there is a \u200e character in the result?

Answer (score 3):

Because your **input** has that character:

```
>>> sent
'下列函数中,值域是(0,+\\\\infty )的共有( )\u200e'
```

All I did was copy your sample first line into my console, then echo the result.

It's a [U+200E LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK codepoint](https://codepoints.net/U+200e), which is used in controlling text direction in multi-script text, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark).

Comment: But I don't add this character to sent, it seems it will be added to sent automatically?

Comment: @maxyue It is there (invisibly) in your string literal. This `'下列函数中,值域是(0,+\\infty )的共有( )‎'` contains the character, but this `'下列函数中,值域是(0,+\\infty )的共有( )'` does not.

Comment: @maxyue: no, the character is not added by anything in Python. It was part of your original source.

Comment: That doen't solve my problem. Indeed, it is in my original sent, and it is invisible, but I don't key in this character to sent.

Comment: @maxyue: is the character actually causing issues? Then simply remove it from your input data. If not, just leave it be.